# SIGILL in Android NDK code

Tags: android, c++, assembly, android-ndk, arm

I have an NDK app out on market and got a native crash report about a `SIGILL` signal. (I use google breakpad to generate native crash reports.) Here are the details:

- My app is compiled for `armeabi-v7a`, **with** NEON support.
- It crashed on a NVIDIA Tegra 2 Processor, which is ARM-7 (Cortex-A9).
- It happens every time. (contacted the user)
- The crash address was at `0x399cc`, the signal was `SIGILL`, and it's in my code.

Registers and disassembly:

```
 r4 = 0x001d50f0    r5 = 0x001d50f0    r6 = 0x598e2a3c    r7 = 0x00000000
 r8 = 0x00000001    r9 = 0x001c22b0   r10 = 0x00000000    fp = 0x81216264
 sp = 0x598e2a18    lr = 0x816399cb    pc = 0x816399cc

0x000399c6 <_ZN8Analyzer15setExpAvgFactorEi+22>:    blx 0x30508
0x000399ca <_ZN8Analyzer15setExpAvgFactorEi+26>:    fconstd d16, #7
0x000399ce <_ZN8Analyzer15setExpAvgFactorEi+30>:    vldr    d17, [pc, #32]  ; 0x399f2 <_ZN8Analyzer15setExpAvgFactorEi+66>
```

Full source and assembler available [here](http://pastebin.com/hqgeKtSG) (it's short, basically 2 lines of C++.)

You can see that `0x399cc` is in the middle of the `fconstd` instruction. According to [arm.com](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204g/CJAEFGHE.html) this instruction was added in `VFP-v3`, which should (I think) be available in any modern processor.

What could be going on? Does the fact that the address is in the *middle* of an instruction point to a corrupt pointer somewhere? (Note that the backtrace makes perfect sense, so it's not like this function was somehow called on accident.) Or is it something else?

Comment: FWIW, an official-seeming answer from NVIDIA regarding VFPv3 support on the Tegra 2 can be found here. (Spoiler: it does, so people looking at that as the issue, as VFPv3 is marked "optional" on the Cortex-A9 series, should look further.) http://developer.nvidia.com/tegra/forum/does-tegra-2-support-vfpv3

Comment: As for the Google Breakpad on Android, there is an open question about that if you want some easy points :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752759/using-google-breakpad-for-android-ndk

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, I got it: the NVIDIA Tegra 2 only has 16 64-bit GPU registers, and therefore to target it you must compile using `-mfpu=vfpv3-d16`. The instruction in question uses register `d16`, which is "just too many". :(

Here is a reference to an NVIDIA forum where an employee mentions this limitation: http://developer.nvidia.com/tegra/forum/optimal-performance-guidelines

Comment: That's it. It also doesn't support NEON instructions. Now the question is... is it safe to assume that all `armeabi-v7a` processors have `vfpv3-d16` support? And is it possible to take advantage of the FPU while still specifying `-mfloat-abi=softfp` (required for Android?)

Comment: I had actually almost included a reference to the Debian ARMEL project's site for this before, but they claimed that "vfpv3-d16" was a good "common denominator". Also (same reference), softfp allows the compiler to "make smart choices about when and if it generates emulated or real FPU instructions depending on chosen FPU type", so it seems like yes: you will be able to take advantage of the FPU with that flag. http://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort/VfpComparison

Comment: Just to provide some additional context to Jay's answer, NEON support mandates 32 FPU registers (see the notes in $NDK/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/machine/cpu-features.h). The Tegra 2 is one of the few ARM devices in the wild with an ARMv7a instruction set but no NEON support. And yes, ARMv7a mandates VFPv3-D16.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put *.so in a folder called 'externallibs' and use it to build by ndk-build, after copy and paste *.so in armeabi-v7a folder.
It helps me.
An other solutions is to remove the Neon Support if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

(I know it's answered but this is the first result i get when searching for NDK SIGILL ARM.)

At least on ARM 32 bits devices (i think it's an architecture thing and not dependent on clang flags or the NDK but i'll gladly be corrected), if you have a function that returns something, like a `int getSomeThing();` and you **don't** have a `return` statement you risk a misterious SIGILL at the end of said function.

So this:

```
int returnSomething() {
  // do stuff
  if(whatever) {
    // more code
  } // SIGILL at the end of the last block or instruction
  // no return 0; here
}
```

will trigger it.